# Covert to Table to css (div)

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I would like to convert this design from Table structure into Divs/CSS. I spent so many times to redo the design on CSS but still stuck!! The idea is to create time table but I used table in my web form instead of Divs. I was trying to redesign but nothing worked for me... 
Any help would be much appreciated

```
<style type="text/css">
    .auto-style3 {
        color: #3366CC;
    }
    .auto-style7 {
        width: 314px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 700;
        text-decoration: underline;
        color: #3366CC;
    }
    .auto-style13 {
        width: 314px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #3366CC;
    }
    .auto-style14 {
        width: 299px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #3366CC;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    .auto-style15 {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    .auto-style16 {
        width: 314px;
        text-align: center;
        height: 22px;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
    .auto-style17 {
        height: 30px;
    }
    .auto-style19 {
        height: 40px;
    }
    .auto-style21 {
        width: 299px;
        text-align: left;
        height: 40px;
    }
    .auto-style22 {
        font-weight: normal;
    }
    .auto-style24 {
        width: 314px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 700;
        height: 39px;
    }
    .auto-style26 {
        width: 314px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 700;
        height: 40px;
    }
    .auto-style28 {
        width: 314px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 700;
        height: 116px;
    }
    .auto-style29 {
        width: 314px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 700;
        height: 153px;
    }
    .auto-style30 {
        width: 299px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 700;
        height: 116px;
    }
    .auto-style31 {
        width: 299px;
        text-align: center;
        height: 22px;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
    .auto-style32 {
        width: 299px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 700;
        height: 153px;
    }
    .auto-style33 {
        width: 299px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 700;
        height: 40px;
    }
    .auto-style34 {
        width: 299px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 700;
        height: 39px;
    }
    .auto-style35 {
        width: 299px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #333333;
    }
    .auto-style36 {
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #333333;
    }
    .auto-style37 {
        color: #333333;
    }
</style>

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1"    
         runat="server">
   <table style="width: 731px">
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style17" colspan="2"> 
  <h2 style="-webkit-text-shadow: 4px 4px 6px rgba(245, 153, 118, 1);
-moz-text-shadow: 4px 4px 6px rgba(245, 153, 118, 1);
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 6px rgba(245, 153, 118, 1);">Classes Timetable</h2>
            <br />
            <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style17" colspan="2">
                 <p style="text-align: left; color: #666666; line- 
      height:140%; width: 716px;" >
                     Text.</p>
             </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style14"><strong><b>Text</b></strong></td>
        <td class="auto-style13"><strong><span class="auto-style15">
   <b>Text </b> </span> </strong> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style30"><strong>Text; <br />
            </strong><span class="auto-style22">Text<br />
            Text</span><br />
            <br />
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style28"><strong>
            Text<br />
            </strong><span class="auto-style22">Text</span><strong><br />
            Text<br />
            </strong><span class="auto-style22">Text</span>
            <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style31"></td>
        <td class="auto-style16"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style31"></td>
        <td class="auto-style16">
            </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style35"><strong>Text</strong></td>
        <td class="auto-style7"><strong><b>Text</b></strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style32">
            <br />

            <span class="auto-style3"><strong>
            Text</strong></span><span class="auto-style22">Text.</span><span    
                                   class="auto-style3"><strong><br />
            Text</strong></span> <span class="auto-style22">Text</span><br/>
            <span class="auto-style3"><strong>Text</strong></span> <span   
     class="auto-style22">Text</span><br />
            (<a href="ContactUs.aspx">Text</a>)</td>
        <td class="auto-style29">

            <strong>

            <span class="auto-style37">Text</span><span class="auto-style3">
                                <br />
            </span><span class="auto-style36">Text
            <br />
           Text</span><span class="auto-style3"><br />
            </span> </strong><br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td class="auto-style21">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style19" colspan="2">Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style33">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"      
     OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">Text</asp:LinkButton>
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style26">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" 
   OnClick="LinkButton2_Click">Text</asp:LinkButton>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style33">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server"   
         OnClick="LinkButton3_Click">Text</asp:LinkButton>
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style26">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" runat="server" 
         OnClick="LinkButton4_Click">Text</asp:LinkButton>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style33">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton5" runat="server" 
          OnClick="LinkButton5_Click">Text</asp:LinkButton>
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style26">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton6" runat="server" 
         OnClick="LinkButton6_Click">Text</asp:LinkButton>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style34">
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style24"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using tables if you actually want to render a table. If you're using tables for other kinds of layout then yes, most front-end devs would agree that's not great, but I think  in your case you do actually want the output to look like a table - yes ?

Comment: “Nothing worked" is not a problem description. Describe the desired result, the best effort so far, and how it fails to achieve the goal. Besides, this seems to be an exercise in futility (rewriting working code for no good reason).

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS tables: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/getting_your_di

You can make divs behave like tables by using `display: table` and `display: table-cell`.

With HTML table elements:

```
<table style="width: 731px">
<tr>
    <td class="auto-style17" colspan="2"> 
     <h2 style="-webkit-text-shadow: 4px 4px 6px rgba(245, 153, 118, 1);
         -moz-text-shadow: 4px 4px 6px rgba(245, 153, 118, 1);
         text-shadow: 4px 4px 6px rgba(245, 153, 118, 1);">Classes Timetable</h2>
        <br />
        <br />
    </td>
</tr>
<table>
```

With CSS tables:

```
<div style="width: 731px; display: table;">
    <div class="auto-style17" style="display: table-cell;"> 
     <h2 style="-webkit-text-shadow: 4px 4px 6px rgba(245, 153, 118, 1);
         -moz-text-shadow: 4px 4px 6px rgba(245, 153, 118, 1);
         text-shadow: 4px 4px 6px rgba(245, 153, 118, 1);">Classes Timetable</h2>
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
```